# How do I add to a formula in Excel to ensure an allocated date is not repeated (except under a certain condition)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My spreadsheet is used to show when something is due by based on a date entered and a frequency given:
[image: Sample of the relevant part of the spreadsheet]

The formula currently used to populate the due date is;

```
=IF(H7="Weekly",G7+7,IF(H7="Fortnightly",G7+14,IF(H7="Three Weekly",G7+21,IF(H7="Monthly",G7+30,IF(H7="2 Months",G7+60,IF(H7="3 Months",G7+90,IF(H7="4 Months",G7+120,IF(H7="5 Months",G7+150,IF(H7="6 Months",G7+180,IF(H7="7 Months",G7+210,IF(H7="8 Months",G7+240,IF(H7="9 Months",G7+270,IF(H7="10 Months",G7+300,IF(H7="11 Months",G7+330,IF(H7="12 Months",G7+365,IF(H7="Initial Visit",G7+31))))))))))))))))*
```

However, this could see multiple things being due on the same date, which I want to avoid to ensure workload is evenly distributed or limited to a maximum of 7 events per week.

What can be added to the existing formula to ensure that there can only be one event on one date and should the existing formula produce a date that is already taken it can allocate it the next available (closest date before or after duplicated due) date?

Comment: I forgot to mention what the condition was!! The condition which would override the duplicate date issue would be where the frequency would be 'Initial Visit' as these are prioritised.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing are very specific conditions and implications which result in long formulas to fully incorporate all of them exactly.

To avoid the lengthy chain of IF clauses in that you have in your formula above, I would suggest splitting the column for the interval selection into two: one for the number value (1,...,n) and one for the interval class (weeks,months,initial visit).

Moreover, as shown in the screenshot below, I added an extra column for the priority of 'Initial Visit' and changed the formula used also for the non-adjusted due date for the new two interval specifying columns.

[image]
As highlighted in yellow, the due date for the 3rd job is being postponed by 1 day to prioritize the 'Initial Visit'.

The formulas are as follows:

- Priority in F4 to F8 is `=($E4="Initial Visit")*EDATE($C4,1)`
- Non-Adjusted Due Date in G4 to G8 is `=IF($E4="Initial Visit",EDATE($C4,1),IF($E4="Weeks",$C4+$D4*7,IF($E4="Months",EDATE($C4,$D4),"")))`
- Adjusted Due Date in H4 to H8 is `=($E4="Months")*(EDATE($C4,$D4)+SUM((($E$4:$E$8="Weeks")*($C$4:$C$8+$D$4:$D$8*7)=EDATE($C4,$D4))+(($F$4:$F$8)=EDATE($C4,$D4)))) +($E4="Weeks")*(($C4+$D4*7)+SUM((($F$4:$F$8)=($C4+$D4*7))+0)) +($E4="Initial Visit")*EDATE($C4,1)`

A few other things should be noted though:

- For the interval classes, only the selection (weeks, months, initial visit) is allowed. 'Fortnightly' or the like would be invalid.
- Same due dates can still exist in the adjusted due date column.
- A priority order has been introduced with the order of (months, weeks, initial visit) in ascending priority.

Meaning, for example, when two jobs have their time period given in the same interval class (e.g. 'Weeks') and the non-adjusted due date falls on the same date, the adjusted due date won't change it.